# '[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user' error

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel, odbc

I am trying to connect to a local network SQL server via excel VBA but I get this run-time error:

`[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'myUID'`

When I use this connection string

`ConnectionString ="Driver={SQL Server};Server=myLocalServer; Database=myDb;trusted_connection=yes;UID=myUID;PW=myPWD;"`

I have Windows Authentication as the Authentication Method for the SQL server.

Do I need SQL and Windows Authentication? Is there something wrong with my connection string?

Comment: If it's using Windows Authentication, take out UID and PW.  Try this, `"Driver={SQL Server};Server=myLocalServer; Database=myDb;trusted_connection=yes;` alone.  You don't have a user named myUID, that's there for example purposes.  myUid would be "user1" and password would be "something else"  [example](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-sql-server-odbc-driver/trusted-connection/)

Comment: @JimmySmith in my attempt using your solution I still caught 'Login failed for user..' when I removed the UID and PW from the connection string

Comment: The error should be completely different if so, Login failed for user 'WindowsUserNameHere'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.  Are you sure it ends with `Trusted_Connection=Yes;` ?  I say so as something else in your code might be setting a userid / password.  Can you post the entire section of the code?

Comment: check if the host name is correct, usually windows shared servers have host at one ip and files at another ip, so don't use localhost, check with the provider and get the correct ip of the database server and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a UID and PW, then it's more than likely a SQL account. Does that account exist in SQL? When you remove UID AND PW, and replace with a trusted connection, it's then using windows authentication. If you do this, make sure your windows account has permissions in SQL.

Comment: I can successfully connect to the SQL server in MSSMS when I use my windows account

Comment: create a generic odbc connection on your computer/laptop, outside of your app, and see if you can connect.

Comment: After creating a generic I got my solution as an owner

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happened is because you're asking it to do both a "trusted connection" and also passing it credentials (with uid and pwd).  You need to remove `trusted_connection=yes;` or remove `UID=myUID;PW=myPWD;`.