# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, sqlsrv, unixodbc

I'm integrating MSSQL Server into my PHP 8.0 application using a Docker container. I've installed the `pdo_sqlsrv`,`sqlsrv` and unixodbc extensions, and for that, I've also installed ODBC Driver 18 for the connection. However, I'm encountering the following error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for
> user: 'ZXV\user.name'.

Here's the code for both SQL Server connection methods:

1. Using SQLSRV Extension:

```php
$serverName = "22.22.22.99,99999"
$connectionInfo = array(
    "UID" => $uid, 
    "PWD" => $pwd, 
    "Database" => $database, 
    "TrustServerCertificate" => true, 
    "Authentication" => "SqlPassword"
);
/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

2. Using PDO SQLSRV:

```php
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=$database;TrustServerCertificate=true;Authentication=SqlPassword", $uid, $pwd);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

With the same credentials I'm able to connect sql server on my php.5.6 and mssql extension using dblib driver.

Is there any changes on ODBC driver 18 or do I need to add some other configuration

I'm trying to establish database connection with sql server

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/38575750/11350193 help ?

Comment: No, I already visited  that post

Comment: `I'm trying to establish database connection`...you've established the connection no problem. The issue is the credentials are wrong, or at least the account doesn't have permission to the database you're trying to access. I appreciate you said you could login using the old driver, but changing drivers doesn't cause a permissions issue. Double-check you're connecting to the same server, same database etc and haven't made any typos.

Comment: Indeed, there are no permission issues with the database and credentials since they work with the existing application, which is on version 5.6 and uses the MSSQL driver. However, upon upgrading it, issues have arisen. Should I consider adding some configuration within the Docker or `odbc.ini` file, or are there additional attributes required in the connection string?

Comment: It wouldn't do any harm to have some extra information. Are you 100% sure that you haven't made any typing errors or similar when transferring the credentials over to the new code?

Comment: Absolutely certain! I'm using the exact same configuration file that's functioning in the existing application, and I've even attempted it with hardcoded values.

Comment: Yes, same user name added in the sql server.

Comment: I can connect to SQL Server using SQL Server Authentication with a username and password, but you are unable to connect using Windows Authentication with domain credentials. The DB team informed me that they added my username to a group within the Windows Active Directory. However, when I try the connection query with that configuration, it doesn't work.

$uid = "domain/user.name"
$conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database = $database;TrustServerCertificate=true;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;", $uid, $pwd);